# LIST alternative in redis

Tags: redis

**Redis.io**

> The main features of Redis Lists from the point of view of time
>   complexity is the support for constant time insertion and deletion of
>   elements near the head and tail, even with many millions of inserted
>   items. Accessing elements is very fast near the extremes of the list
>   but is slow if you try accessing the middle of a very big list, as it
>   is an O(N) operation.

what is the **LIST** alternative when the data is too high and writes are lesser than Reads

Comment: What do you mean by "fata ia too high"?

Comment: when the length of list(llen) is greater than 10lacs

Answer (score 1):

This is something I'd definitely benchmark before doing, but if you're really hitting a performance issue accessing items in the middle of the list, there are a couple of alternatives that really depend on your use case.

1. Don't make a list so big, age out/trim pieces that don't matter any more.
2. Memoize hot sections of the list.  If a particular paginated range is being requested much more often than others, make that it's own list.  Check if it exists already, and if it doesn't create a subset of your list in the paginated range.
3. Bucket your list from the beginning into "manageable sizes" (for whatever your definition of managable is).  If a list is purely additive (no removal from the list), you could use the modulus index of an item as part of the key so that your list is stored in smaller buckets.  Ex: key = "your_key_name_" + index % 100000

Comment: How to know the list length, If i used 3 usecase

Comment: whats about replication?  I mean is it useful in this scenario

Comment: replication/sharding could be useful but it really depends more specifically on what you're doing.  If it's mostly read-only, you could have slaves that are read only that a writable master is feeding.   Again, I'd do some benchmarking with data that simulates what you're trying before making any of these changes.

Comment: how to do the LRANGE as per 3 usecase